# How handle transaction in Chain Of Responsibility pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, transactions, chain, responsibility

I have a transaction issue on COR pattern:

```
       AbstractChainHandler
      |                   |
      |                   |
   FirstChainHandler     SecondChainHandler
    -create A               -create B
    -delete A               -delete B
```

FirstChainHandler and SecondChainHandler both extend AbstractChainHandler and they do some persistence tasks.
Is it possible to handle transaction so if SecondChainHandler fails to save B on db also FirstChainHandler does the rollback of A persistence?

I am trying with spring @Transactional but it is not working and I am not sure if COR pattern matches my goal.
I tryied to change propagation and isolation configurations but it didn't work.

Comment: "if SecondChainHandler fails to save A on db also FirstChainHandler does the rollback of B persistence" -> should it be "if SecondChainHandler fails to save B on db also FirstChainHandler does the rollback of A persistence"?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Two-phase commit protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol#Implementing_the_two-phase_commit_protocol) is what you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

As a first option I would try to combine creation of A and B into single transaction. Maybe it's possible to handle transactions at the base class level? Another option is to combine the classes `FirstChainHandler` and `SecondChainHandler` into one. This would make it easy to handle the transactional part.

The second option adds complexity so I wouldn't go there if not absolutely necessary. With [Saga](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/saga/) and/or [Compensating Transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/compensating-transaction) patterns you can achieve eventual consistency.